# How can I create a listener for new transaction with Ethereum RPC calls?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, filters

I am trying to create mini-service which would allow me to subscribe for incoming Ethereum transactions ([coinbase example](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/notifications)).

I thought that in Ethereum it could be done with `eth_newFilter` and `eth_getFilterChanges` ([JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC))  methods but I am doing something wrong. Could you please give any clue or maybe I completely misunderstood the concept of the filters? I know that there is `eth_newPendingTransactionFilter` method, but I thought maybe there is a better way to achieve my goal? Right now I am following these steps:

**Start geth**

I know that I shouldn't open RPC like this, but right now I have done this for simplicity.

```
geth --dev --rpc --rpcapi "personal,miner,db,shh,admin,eth" --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcport "8545"
```

**Check accounts:**

```
➜  curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params": [],"id":1}' localhost:8545
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[]}
```

**Create two accounts**:

```
➜  curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["password"],"id":1}' localhost:8545
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x0199147554059ce1fa572600256dd6030db19658"}
➜  curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["password"],"id":1}' localhost:8545
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x350060daba130bed0809126c67240d38f27c4cff"}
```

**Start miner:**

```
➜  curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_start","params":["1"],"id":1}' localhost:8545
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":true}
```

**Create new filter:**

```
➜  curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_newFilter","params":[{"address": "0x350060daba130bed0809126c67240d38f27c4cff", "fromBlock":"latest","toBlock":"latest"}],"id":2}' localhost:8545
{"id":2,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x0"}
```

**Unlock account and send transaction:**

```
➜  curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0x0199147554059ce1fa572600256dd6030db19658","password"],"id":1}' localhost:8545
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":true}
➜  curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from": "0x0199147554059ce1fa572600256dd6030db19658","to": "0x350060daba130bed0809126c67240d38f27c4cff", "value":"0x1" }],"id":1}' localhost:8545
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0xd0e910765a920b30fc2e70de6fc4557e74ad69c584d810f70188d254db7119bb"}
```

**Wait for transaction proceed by local node:**

```
➜ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x350060daba130bed0809126c67240d38f27c4cff"],"id":1}' localhost:8545
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x01"}
```

**Check filter and got nothing :(**

```
➜ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getFilterChanges","params":["0x00"],"id":1}' localhost:8545
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[]}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Filters work a little bit different. Filters require `LOG`s to be emitted from an EVM execution (i.e. a contract). Solidity makes this easy for you by allowing you to fire `event`s (compiled `event`s generate `LOG`s).

Let's take the following contract:

```
contract T {
    event res(uint indexed out)
    function echo(uint in) {
         res(i);
    }
}
```

When the method `echo` is invoked on the contract it fires the solidity *event* `res`. These events can be caught using the `eth_newFilter` and queried using `eth_getFilterChanges`.

When creating a filter for a specific event (e.g. `res`) we need to derive the event *signature* first. Signatures are generated using the first 4 bytes of the `keccak` hash of the event's definition (i.e. `res(uint)`): `keccak("res(uint)")`. This then becomes the *first* argument for the `eth_newFilter`'s **topics**.

Any of the arguments in the **definition** of the event that have the `indexed` keyword (as in the example contract listed above) can also be used to filter on. Let's say we only want to catch events for the number **6**, we would then construct the following JSON-RPC:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_newFilter","params":[{"address": "0xaddress", topics:["KECCAK_HASH", "0x6"], "fromBlock":"latest","toBlock":"latest"}],"id":2}' localhost:8545 {"id":2,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x0"}
```

Now whenever the method `echo(6)` is invoked on the contract you'll be able to query the result using the `eth_getFilterChanges`.

Please see the solidity docs on [events](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events) for more information.

Comment: I'm curious how you'd accomplish that same task using web3.js. I believe it would work via https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-allevents but I can't find any good examples for how to construct the topics array.

Comment: @Jeffrey W. top https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newFilter said that: A note on specifying topic filters: Topics are order-dependent. A transaction with a log with topics [A, B] will be matched by the following topic filters: [] "anything"
[A] "A in first position (and anything after)"
[null, B] "anything in first position AND B in second position (and anything after)"
[A, B] "A in first position AND B in second position (and anything after)"
[[A, B], [A, B]] "(A OR B) in first position AND (A OR B) in second position (and anything after)" what does topics means?it seems Arra

Comment: do you know how I can capture all "Transfer" events triggered by a contract on past blocks? Example: say token T wasn created so I'd like to cature every transfer transaction since its creation so I can see where all of the tokens went. Thanks