# Using eth_newFilter

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, ethereumj

referenced by https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newFilter.
I am confused by topic parameter.
Could give some examples?
some information referenced by the following,but I still do not know. [How can I create a listener for new transaction with Ethereum RPC calls?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/how-can-i-create-a-listener-for-new-transaction-with-ethereum-rpc-calls)

Answer (score 3):

The topic is used for filtering on indexed parameters in events/logs. If you have looked at Solidity (the most popular language for writing smart contracts in Ethereum), you can write events with the following format:

```
event myEvent (type1 indexed arg1, type2 indexed arg2, type3 arg3);
```

The `indexed` keyword allows you to filter on it when browsing event logs. For example:

```
"topics": ["0x01","0x02"]
```

would mean you are interested in events that have arg1 and arg2 with values of 1 and 2 respectively. As the documentation details, you can pass null to the first as a wildcard (to accept anything on that topic).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `eth_newFilter` just like this

1 specify your filter params

here is a param demo:

```
params =  {
      "fromBlock": "0x0",
      "toBlock": "latest",
      "address": address,
      "topics": [event_id, None, None]
    }
```

which means look for logs from the genesis block until the recently block mined

`address` varaible use to specfic the where the logs are generated, generally, it's a contract address which you interested

`topics` is the filter params. The first topic is the hash of event signature and the other is the indexed param in event declaration

Here is the [link](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter) with detail information and you can calcu the hash of the event signature via `pyethereuem.ethereum.abi.event_id` method